# Problem mit Qualität der Antworten und Upvotes

Tags: discussion

Es fällt auf, dass Antworten, die bereits viele Upvotes haben, weiter geupvotet werden, ohne dass tatsächlich über deren Inhalt refklektiert wird. Beispielsweise hat diese Frage [Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "reden" und "sprechen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-reden-und-sprechen/) eine Antwort, die meiner Meinung nach absolut ungerechtfertigt eine dichotomische Aussage trifft, die höchstens nur sehr eingeschränkt gültig ist: *sprechen* = "Sprache produzieren", *reden* = "sich unterhalten/Gedanken vermitteln". (Siehe auch meine Kommentare und meine Antwort im verlinkten Thread). Man kann aber kaum Qualität zu solchen Antworten hinzufügen, da weitere Antworten kaum Beachtung finden. Ich finde das problematisch im Hinblick auf Personen, die German Stackexchange besuchen und nach Fragen, die bereits geantwortet wurden, suchen.

Comment: All meta-posts should be in English [because reasons](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/325/15318).

Comment: That’s a general problem of SE sites.

Comment: Und~ gerade mal eine Woche später darf mein obiger Kommentar als revidiert gelten. Feiern! \o/

Comment: Mein altes Mantra: Downvote early, downvote often!

Answer (score 5):

That early and accepted answers have a certain advantage on Stack Exchange is inherent to the system.
Since Stack Exchange came into existance, users have tried to find ways to alleviate this problem, but I am not aware of any solution that has found general acclaim.
If you think you have a brilliant solution to this, you can suggest it on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) or start your own Q&A site, but beware that your suggestion may not be as brilliant as you think it is or it may have been made before. There certainly is no system that makes the best answer be first in every case.

That being said, there is one way to get more people to look at that question and even hint them at your answer: Place a [bounty](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it. For example, until a month ago, [the accepted answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/21522/7734) to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/21521/7734) had only a slightly lower score than the highest scoring answer (proof: [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/21522/timeline), [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/21529/timeline)). A month ago, a new answer was posted and subsequently two bounties were placed on the question (one of which lasted only a day and could not unfold its full potential). Today this answer outscores the accepted one by a factor of three.

In general, you should also consider the possibility that the presumably wrong answer is not as wrong and that your alternative is not as good as you think they are.

Answer (score 3):

Stack-Exchange funktioniert so, dass jemand eine Frage stellt, und andere darauf antworten.

Du stellst hier aber keine Frage, sondern gibst nur deine persönliche Meinung bekannt. Du machst nicht mal einen Änderungsvorschlag. Daher habe ich deine »Frage« zum Schließen markiert, mit der Begründung »unclear what you're asking«.

Aber ich vermute mal dass du möchtest, dass der von dir kritisierte Zustand geändert wird. Da stellt sich natürlich sofort die Frage, wer denn überhaupt diesen Zustand ändern könnte:

1. **Stack-Exchange**

   Die erste Möglichkeit ist, dass die Funktionsweise von Stack-Exchange geändert wird. Da aber das Frage-Antwort-Prinzip mit Bewertungen, die aus der Community kommen, das grundlegende Basis-Prinzip von Stack-Exchange ist, werden wir hier auf der kleinen Beta-Seite »german.stackexchange« dein Problem nicht lösen können, denn es betrifft ja alle Seiten von Stack-Exchange.

   Aber selbst wenn du dich an die richtige Stelle gewandt hättest, würde man dich - wie du vermutlich selbst einsehen wirst - abblitzen lassen, denn du kritisierst genau das grundlegende Fundament auf dem der große Erfolg von Stack-Exchange aufbaut.

   Dieses Fundament darfst du selbstverständlich gerne kritisieren, denn auch ich glaube, dass es nicht perfekt ist. Aber du wirst wahrscheinlich nicht ernsthaft erwarten, dann man daran etwas ändern wird. Immerhin ist Stack-Exchange unter den vielen Millionen Webseiten, die es weltweit gibt, laut [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com) derzeit (24. März 2016) auf Rang 177 der am häufigsten genutzten Webseiten. So viel Erfolgt wünschen sich Millionen andere Internetanbieter (Zum Vergleich: meine eigene Website wissen.schoelnast.at liegt auf Rang 2.357.907)
2. **Andere Benutzer**

   Man könnte irgendwie (wie genau müsste man erst noch klären) die 24 Leute ausfindig machen, die meine Antwort mit +1 bewertet haben, und sie bitten, ihr Voting zu überdenken, und auch die anderen Antworten auf dieselbe Frage noch einmal neu zu bewerten. Ich halte es aber nicht für realistisch, dass viele dieser Leute ihre bereits abgegebene Meinung ändern werden. Ein paar vielleicht, aber sicher nicht alle.
3. **Du selbst**

   Wenn dir meine Antwort nicht gefällt, dann kannst du:

   - Sie mit -1 bewerten
   - Drei Kommentare schreiben, in denen du Argumente anführst, die gegen die Antwort sprechen
   - Eine eigene Antwort schrieben

Den Punkt 3 hast du bereits in vollem Umfang ausgeschöpft (Du könntest höchstens noch mehr Kommentare schreiben). Da du dich aber auch hier auf Meta noch darüber äußerst (wohlgemerkt, ohne dabei irgend etwas zu fragen), scheint dir das nicht zu reichen. Nur sind eben leider die in 1 und 2 angeführten Alternativen unrealistisch, und das wirst du vermutlich auch selbst einsehen.

Also was genau möchtest du mit deinem Posting hier erreichen?

**Nur zum Verständnis:**

Dass viele Leute eine Antwort positiv bewerten, heißt nicht, dass sie richtig ist. Es heißt, am Beispiel der hier thematisierten Antwort, dass 24 Personen finden, dass die Antwort gut ist, während nur 2 finden, dass sie schlecht ist.

Mehr leistet Stack-Exchange nicht, und mehr will es auch gar nicht leisten.

Comment: Also auf meta muss man nicht unbedingt eine Frage stellen. Es geht ja hier um das drumherum und vor allem, dass sich alle wohlfühlen, und ggf. Misstände beseitigt. Ich denke auch, du solltest das nicht zu sehr auf deine Antwort beziehen. Ich finde allerdings, dass du 3. ganz ausgezeichnet zusammen gefasst hast. (+1)

Answer (score -3):

Das Problem hatte ich gestern schon indirekt adressiert beim Thema Rückgängigmachen des Zustands "answered" bei falschen Antworten. Das Grundproblem von StackExchange ist, dass oft vorschnell gevotet wird bzw. auf 'beantwortet' gesetzt wird.

Hier würde helfen, ein System einzubauen, welches Voting und Akzeptieren von Antworten verzögert nach gewissen Regeln, damit den Leuten zu Bedenkzeit verholfen wird.

- Z.B. könnten Votings die ersten 3 Tage unsichtbar bleiben nach dem Prinzip einer geheimen Abstimmung, um andere nicht zu beeinflussen...
- Oder man erlaubt Voting bzw. Akzeptieren erst nach einer Zeit x nach Eingang der letzten Antwort. Somit wird der erste Hype der Antworten abgefangen bevor abgestimmt wird.

Comment: Der richtige Ort, um deine Vorschläge jemanden vorzulegen, der sie (zumindest theoretisch) auch umsetzen könnte, ist htttp://meta.stackexchange.com. Denn hier auf german. stackexchange kann man das Problem nicht lösen.

Comment: Beide Lösungsvorschläge (mal unbenommen, ob hier der richtige Platz dafür ist oder nicht) erscheinen auf den ersten Blick zielführend. Denkt man aber ein bißchen drüber nach, würde bei beiden Ansätzen gerade die *Spontanität* unterdrückt, die vielen Besuchern erlaubt, mal kurz vorbeizuschauen, durchzulesen und ein Vote oder eine Antwort zu geben (auch wenn es möglicherweise suboptimal oder gar falsch ist). Wenn man die Nutzer zwingt, zu jeder sie auch nur marginal interessierenden Frage nach 3 Tagen zurückzukommen, um abzustimmen, würde die Anzahl der Votes sicher um 90% oder mehr zurückgehen.